# Javascript inheritance with private objects - observable pattern more specifically

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, observer-pattern

I've been working on a javascript layer of an application and trying hard to implement OOP as much as possible, mostly to include the Observable/Observer pattern.  Sure I have no idea how to do multiple inheritance (even multiple like Java with interfaces) but I don't really need that for this - I can do a simple test to determine if an object passed has a certain property/function/method).

Anyhow, While I can expose some public methods and have my private methods, once I get into the child class, I find calling parent class methods to result in undefined this or that in Chrome's debugger.  I'd love to be able to abstract this and tried w/ a function.prototype.extend but when that wasn't working, I stripped it down to simple.  Here's the simple javascript code:

```
var Observable = (function () {
    var mArrObservers = undefined;
    var mbChanged = false;

    mArrObservers = new buckets.LinkedList(); // oops this is the buckets js library
    mbChanged = false;

    return ({
        addObserver: function (objObserver) {
            if (objObserver.hasOwnProperty('update'))
                mArrObservers.add(objObserver)
            else
                throw "Observer must have implemented 'update' method";
        },
        clearChanged: function () {
            this.setChanged(false);
        },
        countObservers: function () {
            return (mArrObservers.size());
        },
        deleteObserver: function (objObserver) {
            mArrObservers.remove(objObserver, function (objObserver1, objObserver2) {
                return (objObserver1 == objObserver2);
            });
        },
        deleteObservers: function () {
            mArrObservers.clear();
        },
        hasChanged: function () {
            if (typeof (mbChanged) == "undefined")
                mbChanged = false;

            return (mbChanged);
        },
        notifyObservers: function (objArgument) {
            mArrObservers.forEach(function (objArg) {
                if (objArgument)
                    objArg.update(objArgument);
                else
                    objArg.update();
            });
        },
        setChanged: function (bChanged) {
            if (typeof (bChanged) == "undefined")
                mbChanged = true;
            else
                mbChanged = bChanged;
        }
    });
});

var Entity = (function () {
    var miId = 0;

    var objReturn = new Observable();

    objReturn.prototype.getId = function () {
        if (typeof (miId) == "undefined")
            miId = 0;

        return (miId);
    };

    objReturn.prototype.setId = function (iId) {
        if (typeof (iId) == "undefined")
            miId = 0;
        else
            miId = iId;

        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    };

    return (objReturn);
});

$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        var objEntity = new Entity();

        objEntity.addObserver({
            update: function () {
                alert('Hi');
            }
        });
        objEntity.setChanged();
        objEntity.notifyObservers();
    });
```

Yes the Observable class is very much modeled after the java.util.Observable class but not exact, just what I felt I needed.  When I get to addObserver though, the debugger rejects it as not defined.  What might I be doing wrong?  I have tried many methods, some pure Javascript, others from APIs.  I'm open to thoughts - if a specific API please say what the API is though so I can pursure and investigate it.

Thank you,

Seth

Comment: Setting the "prototype" property on a plain object has no effect (other than to give you a lovely property called "prototype"). The "prototype" property is special when it's a property of a function.

Comment: Is your goal to understand javascript or to write a pubsub client? look at projects like backbone or node's event emitter for an example.

Comment: I use javascript all the time - this is an actual project that I'm trying to write in a more organized fashion than just a scattering of functions in a variety of JS files even if I connect the methods with the (class.prototype.funcName) method of doing things - I can create simple objects but when it comes to reading the code - it gives a migraine and I have to have 20 event handlers happen in an unknown order where an observer system could be written to handle events in a discernible order.

Comment: The only reason I used the prototype thing above was because many of the "tutorials" said to set the prototype of a child class to the parent's prototype or as a few said - a new instance of the parent - and the constructor(which didn't seem to do anything) so I tried both and nothing seems to let me access addObserver through a public version in the Entity class.